# DappNode mainnet syncing stuck

Tags: ethereum

I installed a new machine with DappNode. Admin panel shows that Mainnet syncing is in progress. But it has been stuck at 18% since last 2 days. Message 'Syncing snapshot: 788 / 4286' is not changing.
Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

From System Packages -> ETHChain -> Controls, restarted the process. This resolved the issue.